# How to publish my project on the software center?

Tags: software-center

I have a project which enable to execute commands with the voice, [sbire](https://github.com/GCorbel/sbire).

How can I publish it on the ubuntu's software center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go here : https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/agreements/new/?next=/dev/apps/new/

Then it will redirect you into : https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/apps/new/

Then fill those details & its easy process.